# Idiom for interaction testing

Tags: javascript, testing

I have an object that must create an instance of an object inside itself to avoid leaking state to other invocations of the function on `Factory`, of which there will be only one instance.

```
function Factory() {
}

Factory.prototype.create = function() {
   var builder = new Builder(); //must be newed up
   //...
}
```

But, this prevents me from making assertions about the interaction of the `Factory` and `Builder` because I cannot inject a mock builder.

In JavaScript what is an idiomatic way to circumvent this issue and enable interaction testing. Is this a valid approach?

```
Factory.prototype.create = function(builder) {
   var builder = builder || new Builder(); //must be newed up 
   //...
}
```

Comment: What are "reentrancy reasons"?

Comment: I have changed the terminology. I believe reentrancy was the incorrect term.

Comment: Wait, why is there only one instance of `Factory`? Why not pass the `Builder` constructor to `Factory`?

Comment: The factory is instantiated and injected into other objects as a 'service' by AngularJS' IOC container, which uses the singleton pattern for 'services'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by injecting a function that returned the builder. The function can be trivially stubbed.